# What's the yield keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, yield, keyword

I heard about a "`yield`" keyword in JavaScript. What is it used for and how do I use it?

Comment: He probably means 'Yield' http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/685510-yield-keyword-usage

Comment: it's explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), but I think this only works for firefox, right? How portable is it? Any way to to this on Chrome or node.js? PD: sorry, it's **Javascript v1.7+**, so that's the property to look at when looking for support.

Comment: @Trylks: Generators are available in Node since v0.11.2

Comment: @JanusTroelsen however, only behind a flag. They are supported natively in ioJS

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

Comment: **Beware:** `yield` is not supported by Internet Explorer

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) is pretty good, IMO.

> The function containing the yield keyword is a generator. When you call it, its formal parameters are bound to actual arguments, but its body isn't actually evaluated. Instead, a generator-iterator is returned. Each call to the generator-iterator's next() method performs another pass through the iterative algorithm. Each step's value is the value specified by the yield keyword. Think of yield as the generator-iterator version of return, indicating the boundary between each iteration of the algorithm. Each time you call next(), the generator code resumes from the statement following the yield.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco there is a very obviously-placed example if you click through to the MDN documentation.

Comment: @MattBall - would a function as javascript for PI like this be sufficient as follows: function * PI { PI = (( Math.SQRT8; ) / 9801;); } - or is there already a function implemented in javascript for this calculation of PI ?

Comment: @dschinn1001 this comment is entirely unrelated to the question here. That said: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI

Comment: What's the point of quoting MDN here? I think everyone can read that on MDN. Visit https://davidwalsh.name/promises to learn more about them.

Comment: How did this get ~80 upvotes when (a) it is a copy of the "very poor documentation" as the questioner calls it and (b) it says nothing helpful? Far better answers below.

Comment: if someone asks for explanation, just copy pasting a documentation is totally unuseful. Asking means that you already searched in docs but you did not understand them.

Comment: its just a function that saves its state.

Comment: MDN docs are the most incomprehensible on JS, using a lot of technical words when you just want to know "what" it does, that's it.

Answer (score 267):

Adapting an example from ["Javascript's Future: Generators"](http://jlongster.com/Javascript-s-Future--Generators) by James Long for the official Harmony standard:

```
function * foo(x) {
    while (true) {
        x = x * 2;
        yield x;
    }
}
```

> "When you call foo, you get back a Generator object which has a next
> method."

```
var g = foo(2);
g.next(); // -> 4
g.next(); // -> 8
g.next(); // -> 16
```

So `yield` is kind of like `return`: you get something back.  `return x` returns the value of `x`, but `yield x` returns a function, which gives you a method to iterate toward the next value.  Useful if you have a [potentially memory intensive procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815278/porting-invregex-py-to-javascript-node-js) that you might want to interrupt during the iteration.

Comment: Helpful, but i guess you its `function* foo(x){` there

Comment: @RanaDeep: [The function syntax is extended to add an *optional* `*` token](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators). Whether or not you need it depends upon the kind of future you are returning. The detail is long: [GvR explains it for the Python implementation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-tulip/bmphRrryuFk/aB45sEJUomYJ), upon which the Javascript implementation is modeled.  Using `function *` will always be right, though in some cases slightly more overhead than `function` with `yield`.

Comment: @bishop I think you're interpreting that wrong. The page does say "The function syntax is extended to add an _optional_ * token", but then goes on to say "A function with a * token is known as a generator function." and "An early error is raised if a yield or yield* expression occurs in a non-generator function." Plus, Babel [considers the above code to be a syntax error](https://goo.gl/ZHKgkt). The code above is broken, and won't work without a `*` added after the `function` keyword.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yep, you're right. Harmony standardized the correlation between `function *` and `yield`, and added the quoted error ("An early error is raised if a yield or yield* expression occurs in a non-generator function").  But, the original Javascript 1.7 implementation in Firefox [didn't require the `*`](https://web.archive.org/web/20130823145610/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7). Updated answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: just for info , this kind of concept is also there in C#

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Js is finally becomes a language you can actualy use. It's called evolution.

Comment: example is useful,but...what's a function * ?

Answer (score 113):

***It's Really Simple, This is how it works***

- `yield` keyword simply helps to **pause** and **resume** a function in any time **asynchronously**.
- Additionally it helps to **return value** from a **generator function**.

Take this simple **generator** function:

```
function* process() {
    console.log('Start process 1');
    console.log('Pause process2 until call next()');

    yield;

    console.log('Resumed process2');
    console.log('Pause process3 until call next()');

    let parms = yield {age: 12};
    console.log("Passed by final process next(90): " + parms);

    console.log('Resumed process3');
    console.log('End of the process function');
}
```

> let  _process = process();

Until you call the ***_process.next()*** it **wont** execute the **first 2 lines** of code, then the **first yield** will **pause** the function.
To **resume** the function *until next **pause*** point (**yield keyword**) you need to call ***_process.next()***.

> You can think multiple **yields** are the **breakpoints** in a javascript debugger within a single function. Until
> you tell to navigate next breakpoint it wont execute the code
> block. (**Note**: without blocking the whole application)

But while yield performs this pause and resume behaviours it can **return some results** as well `{value: any, done: boolean}`
according to the previous function we haven't emit any values. If we explore the previous output it will show the same `{ value: undefined, done: false }`
with value **undefined**.

Lets dig in to the yield keyword. Optionally you can add **expression** and set **assign a default optional value**. (Official doc syntax)

```
[rv] = yield [expression];
```

**expression**: Value to return from the generator function

```
yield any;
yield {age: 12};
```

**rv**: Returns the optional value that passed to the generator's next() method

> Simply you can pass parameters to process() function with this mechanism, to execute different yield parts.

```
let val = yield 99; 

_process.next(10);
now the val will be 10
```

[Try It Now](https://jsfiddle.net/noelyahan/cu2ysmon/7/)

***Usages***

- Lazy evaluation
- Infinite sequences
- Asynchronous control flows

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield
- http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/09/16/generators-and-yield-in-es6/
- https://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-generators-node-js-yield-use-cases/
- https://medium.com/vptech/a-practical-introduction-to-constraint-programming-2037c91833ba

Answer (score 59):

Simplifying/elaborating on Nick Sotiros' answer (which I think is awesome), I think it's best to describe how one would start coding with `yield`.

In my opinion, the biggest advantage of using `yield` is that it will eliminate all the nested callback problems we see in code. It's hard to see how at first, which is why I decided to write this answer (for myself, and hopefully others!)

The way it does it is by introducing the idea of a co-routine, which is a function that can voluntarily stop/pause until it gets what it needs. In javascript, this is denoted by `function*`. Only `function*` functions can use `yield`.

Here's some typical javascript:

```
loadFromDB('query', function (err, result) {
  // Do something with the result or handle the error
})
```

This is clunky because now all of your code (which obviously needs to wait for this `loadFromDB` call) needs to be inside this ugly looking callback. This is bad for a few reasons...

- All of your code is indented one level in
- You have this end `})` which you need to keep track of everywhere
- All this extra `function (err, result)` jargon
- Not exactly clear that you're doing this to assign a value to `result`

On the other hand, with `yield`, all of this can be done in *one line* with the help of the nice co-routine framework.

```
function* main() {
  var result = yield loadFromDB('query')
}
```

And so now your main function will yield where necessary when it needs to wait for variables and things to load. But now, in order to run this, you need to call a *normal* (non-coroutine function). A simple co-routine framework can fix this problem so that all you have to do is run this:

```
start(main())
```

And start is defined (from Nick Sotiro' answer)

```
function start(routine, data) {
    result = routine.next(data);
    if(!result.done) {
        result.value(function(err, data) {
            if(err) routine.throw(err); // continue next iteration of routine with an exception
            else start(routine, data);  // continue next iteration of routine normally
        });
    }
}
```

And now, you can have beautiful code that is much more readable, easy to delete, and no need to fiddle with indents, functions, etc.

An interesting observation is that in this example, `yield` is actually just a keyword you can put before a function with a callback.

```
function* main() {
  console.log(yield function(cb) { cb(null, "Hello World") })
}
```

Would print "Hello World". So you can actually turn any callback function into using `yield` by simply creating the same function signature (without the cb) and returning `function (cb) {}`, like so:

```
function yieldAsyncFunc(arg1, arg2) {
  return function (cb) {
    realAsyncFunc(arg1, arg2, cb)
  }
}
```

Hopefully with this knowledge you can write cleaner, more readable code that is [easy to delete](http://programmingisterrible.com/post/139222674273/write-code-that-is-easy-to-delete-not-easy-to)!

Comment: a `function*` is just a regular function without a yield?

Comment: I think you mean that `function *` is a function that _contains_ yield. It's a special function called a generator.

Comment: For people who already use `yield` everywhere, I'm sure this makes more sense than the callbacks, but I fail to see how this is any more readable than callbacks.

Comment: that article is hard to understand

Comment: so far callback looks simple and intuitive than yield

Answer (score 25):

**`Yield` keyword in javaScript function makes it generator,**

What is generator in JavaScript?

> A generator is a function that produces a sequence of results instead of a single value, i.e. you generate ​a series of values

Meaning generators helps us work asynchronously with the help iterators, Oh now what the hack iterators are? really?

> Iterators are mean through which we are able to access items one at a time

From where iterator help us accessing item one at a time?
It help us accessing items through generator functions, generator functions are those in which we use `yield` keyword, yield keyword help us in pausing and resuming execution of function.

Here is quick example:

```js
function *getMeDrink() {

    let question1 = yield 'soda or beer'; // execution will pause here because of yield
       
    if (question1 == 'soda') {
        return 'here you get your soda';
    }

    if (question1 == 'beer') {

        let question2 = yield 'What\'s your age'; // execution will pause here because of yield

        if (question2 > 18) {
            return "ok you are eligible for it";
        } else {
            return "Shhhh!!!!";
        }
    }
}

let _getMeDrink = getMeDrink(); // initialize it

_getMeDrink.next().value; // "soda or beer"

_getMeDrink.next('beer').value; // "What's your age"

_getMeDrink.next('20').value; // "ok you are eligible for it"

_getMeDrink.next().value; // undefined
```

Let me briefly explain what is going on

You noticed execution is being paused at each `yield` keyword and we are able to access first `yield` with help of iterator `.next()`

This iterates to all `yield` keywords one at a time and then returns undefined when there is no more `yield` keywords left in simple words you can say `yield` keyword is break point where function each time pauses and only resume when call it using iterator for our case: `_getMeDrink.next()` this is example of iterator that is helping us accessing each break point in function.

Example of Generators:
`async/await`

If you see implementation of `async/await` you will see `generator functions & promises`  are used to make `async/await` work please point out any suggestions is welcomed.

Comment: The most didactic answer!!  

Answer (score 19):

To give a complete answer: `yield` is working similar to `return`, but in a generator.

As for the commonly given example, this works as follows:

```
function *squareGen(x) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        yield i*i;
    }
}

var gen = squareGen(3);

console.log(gen.next().value); // prints 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // prints 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // prints 4
```

But theres also a second purpose of the yield keyword. It can be used to send values to the generator.

To clarify, a small example:

```
function *sendStuff() {
    y = yield (0);
    yield y*y;
}

var gen = sendStuff();

console.log(gen.next().value); // prints 0
console.log(gen.next(2).value); // prints 4
```

This works, as the value `2` is assigned to `y`, by sending it to the generator, after it stopped at the first yield (which returned `0`).

This enables us to to some really funky stuff. (look up coroutine)

Answer (score 17):

It's used for iterator-generators.  Basically, it allows you to make a (potentially infinite) sequence using procedural code.  See [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Generators_and_iterators).

Answer (score 6):

`yield` can also be used to eliminate callback hell, with a coroutine framework.

```
function start(routine, data) {
    result = routine.next(data);
    if(!result.done) {
        result.value(function(err, data) {
            if(err) routine.throw(err); // continue next iteration of routine with an exception
            else start(routine, data);  // continue next iteration of routine normally
        });
    }
}

// with nodejs as 'node --harmony'
fs = require('fs');
function read(path) {
    return function(callback) { fs.readFile(path, {encoding:'utf8'}, callback); };
}

function* routine() {
    text = yield read('/path/to/some/file.txt');
    console.log(text);
}

// with mdn javascript 1.7
http.get = function(url) {
    return function(callback) { 
        // make xhr request object, 
        // use callback(null, resonseText) on status 200,
        // or callback(responseText) on status 500
    };
};

function* routine() {
    text = yield http.get('/path/to/some/file.txt');
    console.log(text);
}

// invoked as.., on both mdn and nodejs

start(routine());
```

Answer (score 5):

Fibonacci sequence generator using the yield keyword.

```
function* fibonacci() {
    var a = -1, b = 1, c;
    while(1) {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        yield c;
    }   
}

var fibonacciGenerator = fibonacci();
fibonacciGenerator.next().value; // 0 
fibonacciGenerator.next().value; // 1
fibonacciGenerator.next().value; // 1
fibonacciGenerator.next().value; // 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Dependency between async javascript calls.

Another good example of how yield can be used.

```js
function request(url) {
  axios.get(url).then((reponse) => {
    it.next(response);
  })
}

function* main() {
  const result1 = yield request('http://some.api.com' );
  const result2 = yield request('http://some.otherapi?id=' + result1.id );
  console.log('Your response is: ' + result2.value);
}

var it = main();
it.next()
```

Comment: Beautiful example and exactly what I was looking for to understand. Without the request() function it was not clear to me who is calling the it.next() with a value.

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to understand the yield keyword. Based my current understanding, in generator, yield keyword works like a CPU context-switch. When yield statement is run, all states (for example, local variables) are saved.

Besides this, a direct result object will be returned to the caller, like { value: 0, done: false }. The caller can use this result object to decide whether to 'wake up' the generator again by calling next() (calling next() is to iterate the execution).

Another important thing is that it can set a value to a local variable. This value can be passed by the 'next()' caller when 'waking up' the generator. for example, it.next('valueToPass'), like this: "resultValue = yield slowQuery(1);" Just like when waking up a next execution, caller can inject some running result to the execution (injecting it to local variable). Thus, for this execution, there are two kind of state:

1. the context that saved in the last execution.
2. The injected values by this execution's trigger.

So, with this feature, the generator can sort out multiple async operations. The result of first async query will be passed to the second one by setting local variable (resultValue in above example). The second async query can only be triggered by the first's async query's response. Then the second async query can check the local variable value to decide next steps because the local variable is an injected value from first query’s response.

The difficulties of async queries are:

1. callback hell
2. lose of context unless passing them as parameters in the callback.

yield and generator can help on both.

Without yield and generator, to sort out multiple async query requires nested callback with parameters as context which does not easy to read and maintain.

Below is a chained async queries example which running with nodejs:

```
const axios = require('axios');

function slowQuery(url) {        
    axios.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
            it.next(1);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
            it.next(0);
    })
}

function* myGen(i=0) {
    let queryResult = 0;

    console.log("query1", queryResult);
    queryResult = yield slowQuery('https://google.com');


    if(queryResult == 1) {
        console.log("query2", queryResult);
        //change it to the correct url and run again.
        queryResult = yield slowQuery('https://1111111111google.com');
    }

    if(queryResult == 1) {
        console.log("query3", queryResult);
        queryResult =  yield slowQuery('https://google.com');
    } else {
        console.log("query4", queryResult);
        queryResult = yield slowQuery('https://google.com');
    }
}

console.log("+++++++++++start+++++++++++");
let it = myGen();
let result = it.next();
console.log("+++++++++++end+++++++++++");
```

Below is the running result:

+++++++++++start+++++++++++

query1 0

+++++++++++end+++++++++++

query2 1

query4 0

Below state pattern can do the similar thing for above example:

```
const axios = require('axios');

function slowQuery(url) {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            sm.next(1);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            sm.next(0);
        })
}

class StateMachine {
        constructor () {
            this.handler = handlerA;
            this.next = (result = 1) => this.handler(this, result);
        }
}

const handlerA = (sm, result) => {
                                    const queryResult = result; //similar with generator injection
                                    console.log("query1", queryResult);
                                    slowQuery('https://google.com');
                                    sm.handler = handlerB; //similar with yield;
                                };

const handlerB = (sm, result) => {
                                    const queryResult = result; //similar with generator injection
                                    if(queryResult == 1) {
                                        console.log("query2", queryResult);
                                        slowQuery('https://1111111111google.com');
                                    }
                                    sm.handler = handlerC; //similar with yield;
                                };

const handlerC = (sm, result) => {
                                    const queryResult = result; //similar with generator injection;
                                    if (result == 1 ) {
                                        console.log("query3", queryResult);
                                        slowQuery('https://google.com');
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("query4", queryResult);
                                        slowQuery('https://google.com');
                                    }
                                    sm.handler = handlerEnd; //similar with yield;
                                };

const handlerEnd = (sm, result) => {};

console.log("+++++++++++start+++++++++++");
const sm = new StateMachine();
sm.next();
console.log("+++++++++++end+++++++++++");
```

Following is the running result:

+++++++++++start+++++++++++

query1 0

+++++++++++end+++++++++++

query2 1

query4 0

Answer (score 1):

> hi, if you reached this point it means you all previous answers didn't satisfy your expectations, so i'll make it easy to understand...

```
function * y(){
    const r = yield;
    /** program continue after next() call... **/
}
```

> so first...

- y() is NOT a function, is a GENERATOR.
- generators are called generators because they can generate multiple returns.
- generator pauses the execution when 'yield' is encountered.
- you can add as many yield you need.
- all code after yield will not execute before you call next(see below).
- generators can be used with async/await.
- generators unlike functions can have x number or returns
- calling yield is like calling return.
- you get the value from yield with property .value... (see below).
- remember that the first next() call will just reach the yield and wait for the next "next()" call where you actually handling something, so...
  call.next() will reach the break point, and the following call.next('something in here') will do something after the execution pause...

> **THE MOST MINIMALISTIC EXAMPLE**

```
function * f(){
       const u = yield; // pause here ...
       return u; // something with u after 2nd next() call (see below)
    }

const call = f();
call.next(); // will get to yield(first yield) and wait
call.next('wow'); // as we have 1 yield in the generator, the second next() call will reach the return point where you will get 'wow' as you passed a string 'wow' as the second next() call argument, you can obviously pass in whatever you want(callbacks, string, objects...)
```

> hope i was clear and easy to follow... remember there is the official MDN documentation you can search for at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

Answer (score 0):

Before you learn about yield you need to know about generators. Generators are created using the `function*` syntax. Generator functions do not execute code but instead returns a type of iterator called a generator. When a value is given using the `next` method, the generator function keeps executing until it comes across a yield keyword. Using `yield` gives you back an object containing two values, one is value and the other is done (boolean). The value can be an array, object etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
const strArr = ["red", "green", "blue", "black"];

const strGen = function*() {
    for(let str of strArr) {
        yield str;
    }
};

let gen = strGen();

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(gen.next())
}

//prints: {value: "red", done: false} -> 5 times with different colors, if you try it again as below:

console.log(gen.next());

//prints: {value: undefined, done: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't forget the very helpful 'x of generator' syntax to loop through the generator.  No need to use the next() function at all.

```
function* square(x){
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        x = x * 2;
        yield x;        
    }   
}

var gen = square(2);
for(x of gen){
   console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: and that would be because the generator is an iterator I presume.