# Return from a for loop but keep loop running

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that needs to return something on every iteration:

```
for(var i=0;i<100;++i) {
    return i;
}
```

but return breaks the loop. How can I return but kee the loop running?

Comment: What do you expect it to return, then?

Comment: You can't. What you can do however, is push the return value to an array for example. Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Depending on your target system, [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Generators) could be a solution ([so-question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282140/whats-the-yield-keyword-in-javascript)).

Comment: Return something to _where?_ By definition a function only returns one "thing", though that "thing" may be an array or object that contains multiple values. (Unless `yield` works for your situation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the values you need to return in an array, then after the loop, return the array.

Answer (score 13):

Store it inside an array.

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    array.push(i);
}
```

Comment: @Doorknob This is not Java.

Comment: thought as much. I can't use an array in this instance.

Comment: @MikeRifgin Then what do you want it to return?

Answer (score 5):

The context here is unclear. If you are trying to execute a function for each iteration of the loop, why not something simple like calling a function from within the loop?

```
for(var i=0;i<100;++i) {
    processIteration(i)
}
```

In `processIteration` you could simply handle what you need to happen with that value.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to solve this

1. Promises

```js
function loop() {
  promises = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    // push a promise resolve to a promises array
    promises[i] = Promise.resolve(i);
  }
  return promises;
}

// Observe the promises loop
for (let p of loop()) {
  p.then(console.log)
}
```

2. Callbacks

```js
function loop(cb) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    // calling the callback 
    cb(i);
  }
}

// Pass a do something method
// Here it's the console log as the callback
loop(console.log)
```

3. Yield

```js
// Generator function for loop over 100
function* loop() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      // return value from loop 
      yield i;
  }
}

// Initialize the generator function
let it = loop();

// Call and get the resulr
// it.next().value
var result = it.next();
while (!result.done) {
  console.log(result.value); // 1 2 3 .... 99
  result = it.next();
}
```