# Placeholder product in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## React.js PlaceHolder Product

im want to add pre-load like skeleton loader in my react app for example add 10 or 20 placeHolder but
want without array.map or forEach because im need this placeholder in zero length response time
if im using forEach dont working if you can Help me to fix this, thank you.
[demo placeHolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4og9J.png)

and im try for loop in funtion but not working
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIwDa.png)

```
function placeHolders(){
    for (let i = 1; i <=20; i++){
        return(
          <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={i}>
              <Card.Img
                variant="top"
                src="https://kubalubra.is/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/default-thumbnail.jpg"
              />
              <Card.Body>
                <Placeholder as={Card.Title} animation="glow">
                  <Placeholder xs={6} />
                </Placeholder>
                <Placeholder as={Card.Text} animation="glow">
                  <Placeholder xs={7} /> <Placeholder xs={4} />{" "}
                  <Placeholder xs={4} /> <Placeholder xs={6} />{" "}
                  <Placeholder xs={8} />
                </Placeholder>
                <Placeholder.Button variant="primary" xs={6} />
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        )
      
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">
      {products.length <= 0 &&
      placeHolders()
      }
      {renderList}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductComponents;
```

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: @Konrad im add my Code

Comment: You are returning in the first iteration. You can't just use `return` like that in the loop. You have to create an array and push it into it. Usually `map` is used instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return from a for loop but keep loop running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565630/return-from-a-for-loop-but-keep-loop-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Placeholders = () => (
    <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
       <Card.Img
         variant="top"
         src="https://kubalubra.is/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/default-thumbnail.jpg"
       />
       <Card.Body>
         <Placeholder as={Card.Title} animation="glow">
           <Placeholder xs={6} />
         </Placeholder>
         <Placeholder as={Card.Text} animation="glow">
           <Placeholder xs={7} /> <Placeholder xs={4} />{" "}
           <Placeholder xs={4} /> <Placeholder xs={6} />{" "}
           <Placeholder xs={8} />
         </Placeholder>
         <Placeholder.Button variant="primary" xs={6} />
       </Card.Body>
     </Card>
)
const Ar = Array(20).fill()
return (
    <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">
      {!products.length &&
      Ar.map((item, index) => {return(
        <Placeholders key={index}/>
      )})
      }
      {renderList}
    </div>
);
}

export default ProductComponents;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of doing it. For convenience, lets put your card into separate component named `Placeholder`

```
const Placeholder = () => (
           <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={i}>
              <Card.Img
                variant="top"
                src="https://kubalubra.is/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/default-thumbnail.jpg"
              />
              <Card.Body>
                <Placeholder as={Card.Title} animation="glow">
                  <Placeholder xs={6} />
                </Placeholder>
                <Placeholder as={Card.Text} animation="glow">
                  <Placeholder xs={7} /> <Placeholder xs={4} />{" "}
                  <Placeholder xs={4} /> <Placeholder xs={6} />{" "}
                  <Placeholder xs={8} />
                </Placeholder>
                <Placeholder.Button variant="primary" xs={6} />
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
    )
```

Now you have few options. Render it using map inside of your component return

```
return (
   ...
   {!products.length && (
      {Array(20).fill().map(() => <Placeholder />)}
   ) : (
      {renderList}
   )}
   ...
)
```

Or you can pre-create that placeholders and use when you need like:

```
const placeholders = Array(20).fill().map(() => <Placeholder />)
...

return (
 ...
 {placeholders}
 ...
)
```

Comment: Thank You, im fix my code with your Help