# NodeJS exif returns undefined

Tags: node.js, exif

Im trying to get exif info from my images. So I've made some scratch. It works but it does not work while using it in the loop

Hi. Im trying to get exif info from my images. So I've made this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mime = require('mime');
const exif = require('exif-reader');
const ExifImage = require('exif').ExifImage;

function getFiles(dir, files = []) {
  const fileList = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  for (const file of fileList) {
    const name = `${dir}/${file}`;
    if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
      getFiles(name, files);
    } else {
      files.push(name);
    }
  }
  return files;
}

function getEXIF(filepath){
    try {
        new ExifImage({ image : filepath }, function (error, exifData) {
            if (error)
                console.log('Error: '+error.message);
            else
                console.log(exifData.image); 
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    }
}


//getEXIF('D://MyTestImage.jpg')


const filearr=getFiles('D://Photoes', files = [])
filearr.forEach((element) => {
     const ftype=mime.getType(element)
     if (ftype=='image/jpeg'){
         console.log(getEXIF(element))
     }
 }
 );
```

When I run the function getEXIF for one specific file it works OK. But when I'm trying to use it in foreach loop it returns undefined. Why?. Im sure that element contains path to file because it works perfect for mime.getType function and returns a value.

Please point my mistake.

Comment: Because you didn't return anything, so it returns nothing (undefined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return from a for loop but keep loop running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565630/return-from-a-for-loop-but-keep-loop-running)

Comment: But getEXIF has console.log(exifData.image) shouldn't it print result? Why it works without loop and does not work while in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist, you need to refactor your `getEXIF()` to return the exif data. Since you are not returning anything, you get `undefined`.

Second, the `ExifImage` accepts a callback, which provides the `exifData` as the second argument.

```
function (error, exifData) {}
```

The easiest way to get the `exifData` from the callback, and use that to respond back from `getEXIF` is use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

We shall wrap getEXIF within a promise, and then respond back from the `ExifImage` callback using `reject` or `resolve`.

```
async function getEXIF(filepath) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       try {
           new ExifImage({ image : filepath }, function (error, exifData) {
               if (error)
                   reject(error);
               else
                   resolve(exifData.image); 
           });
       } catch (error) {
           reject(error);
       }
   });
}
```

And you can then use it as:

```
const exif = await getEXIF('D://MyTestImage.jpg');
console.log(exif)
```