# How to perform a simple yield in javascript/node....?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yield

I have tried a few combinations of the below to no effect. I simply want to pause execution and return to the router function when ready and then release the response. Is this possible?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var result = getJson();

    res.render('index', { title: result});

});


function *getJson(){
    yield request('https://myjson.json', function (error, response, body){
        return body;
    });
}




module.exports = router;
```

Comment: you're yielding the return of request(), not `body` being returned inside of it.

Comment: I don't see any simple and clean way to use yield here (ugly convoluted ways are described [here](http://davidwalsh.name/async-generators)). Promises are probably the solution you need until ES7.

Comment: If you just want the JSON to be sent back just put the `res.render` into the `request` callback. You don't need to yield anything, unless you have some higher-level end goal, let the event loop handle it.

Comment: You could use a generator for this like this: http://jsfiddle.net/oybcq94g/ however that likely defeates the purpose of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `async`/`await`, not `yield`. `yield` is used when you want to enumerate. You can read more about it on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282165/1654818).

`async`/`await` are both ECMAScript 7 language features, so they are not available natively in the browsers yet. You could use the [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) compiler to translate/compile/transpile ES7 code into ES5 code, but I haven't tried it. An [example can be found here](http://goo.gl/Dc6V1B).

It is possible to use `generator`s and `yield` in a similar manner to `async`/`await`, [check out this article by Jake Archibald](http://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) for the details.

Comment: oh rubbish it will be years until that is implemented then?

Comment: Since you are using NodeJS, you might be able to use https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait. Or just use Traceur to compile the ES7 code into something usable today, which also works in the browser!