# Make a javascript function that generates a sequential number on each execution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, function, express

So i'd like to make a function that sequentially generates a number each execution, I was wondering how to do this in Javascript I need this to basically set an order to my items in mongoDB. How can I write a JS function that generates a number sequentially each time it's run? ex: 1... then run the function again...2 then again...3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282140/whats-the-yield-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: `yield` is still (too) rare in JavaScript implementations.

Comment: The "sad" thing here is that the [tag:mongodb] tag in the question leads me to believe you actually wanted this: [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/), yet just got "owned" for lack of research and asking more in terms of a [tag:javascript] question than explaining what you were going to use it for.

Comment: @BlakesSeven how did I get owned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var next = (function() {
  var v = 0;
  return function() {
    return v++;
}})();

console.log(next()); // 0
console.log(next()); // 1
console.log(next()); // 2
```