# What should I use instead of a "for" loop when appending a number?

Tags: javascript

I have heard that the `for(){...}` loop in JavaScript is *passé* and should not be used in favor of other, clearer alternatives.  JSLint goes so far as to throw an error when it encounters one (unless you override it, of course).  I understand using `Array.prototype.forEach()` when the situation allows, but *in this instance* what alternative could I use that would be "clearer"?

```
var number = 5;
for (var i=0; i <= number; i++){ 
    log("somestring" + i);
}
```

In `C#` I would use a `foreach(){...}` over `Enumerable.Range(0, 5)` - but I know of no such alternative in JavaScript. I could create an array of digits 0...5 but that seems like going the long way for no gain.

**Edit 1**

I am not looking for an alternative plugin to implement this like lodash or jQuery, and my question really isn't about "why does JSLint...".  What *native JavaScript* alternative would I use?

Comment: Have you considered lodash ? It includes the range function you are looking for https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#range

Comment: JSLint throws an error because your loop only iterate once (because of the `return` statement) thus it is useless. Your whole code is the same as: `return "somestring" + 0;`.

Comment: in jQuery may be $.each can help you?

Comment: try array.map()

Comment: pass two parameters into the callback, the 2nd is the index. `arr.forEach(function(item, i){ console.log(item, i); });`

Comment: Ok, I screwed up the example - I'll fix it.

Comment: That example makes no sense

Comment: I said I would fix it - is that why you downvoted?

Comment: Array Methods... look into them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Javascript does have a yield (return) - perhaps a better candidate for your example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859859/314291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an array to store your numbers, use `.reduce()`:

```
const num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const val = num.reduce((acc, curr) => `${acc}${curr}`, 'somestring')
console.log(val)
```

Edit: The thing is, if you don't want to use an array then the for loop would be the most readable. My advice is to just ignore what JSLint says.

I'll just post another suggestion. It uses the array indexes to generate an array:

```
[...Array(5).keys()].reduce((acc, curr) => `${acc}${curr + 1}`, 'somestring')
```

Comment: " I could create an array of digits 0...5 but that seems like going the long way for no gain."

Comment: Reducing or folding strings causes the string concatenation problem.

Answer (score 1):

`return` is not a good idea in between a loop in javascript.this overridden due to the same you can use `break` or `continue` instead to break the execution in between. There also to get the data as `foreach` jquery also allowed object map to the same as follows. 
and get the value for each as a dynamic string you can work as per the function is given below.

```
var number = 5;
var toReturn = function(){
var ar_data = []; 
for (var i=0; i <= number; i++){ 
    ar_data[i] = "somestring" + i;  // Store your dynamic string into a variable
}
return ar_data; // return array 
}
var data = toReturn(number);

for(dt in data) // foreach type object mapping and tracing 
{
console.log(data[dt]); //print the individual item in array.
}
```