# javascript async/sync file loading

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures, yield

this is the first one of a series of questions i want to submit:
in a given point of a es6 js book ,reading a file is done by the aid
of new yield token,but some syntax is odd to me can you explain me 
whats happening under the hood?

```
run(function*()
let contents=yield readFile("config.json");
dosomething(contents);
console.log("done");
});
```

Till now its was done async by:

```
let fs=require("fs")

function readFile(filename){
 return function(callback){
 fs.readFile(filename,callback);
  };
 };
```

it claims same scheme (first one) can do sync and async loading of file
but it seems that adds some node.js i does not understand
In the second form this is a'functional closure' how does it work or its
called?

Comment: The first one is the deprecated workaround for the new `async` / `await` syntax.

Comment: See [What's the yield keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2282140/3853934)

Comment: @JonasW. Apparently the `run` function for the generator expects thunks that take a callback, and `readFile` was generating such one. It's probably explained in the chapter about the `run` function (if it is not, that book should be thrown away)

Comment: thx Bergi i continue reading