# How does yield work as a argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, yield

I came across this code while learning about yield and wondering what yield would do as a argument to a function . Looks like a glorified return in this place

```
export function * throttle(func, time) {
  let timerID = null;
  function throttled(arg) {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerID = setTimeout(func.bind(window, arg), time); // what does this do????
  }
  while(true) throttled(yield);
}

export class GeneratorThrottle {

  constuctor() {};

  start = () => {
    thr = throttle(console.log, 3000);
    thr.next('');
  };

  toString = () => {
    console.log(throttle);
    console.log('start =', this.start);
  };
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the yield keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282140/whats-the-yield-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `next` method, You can pass data as argument into generator function.

```js
function* logGenerator() {
  console.log(0);
  console.log(1, yield);
  console.log(2, yield);
  console.log(3, yield);
}

var gen = logGenerator();

// the first call of next executes from the start of the function
// until the first yield statement
gen.next();             // 0
gen.next('pretzel');    // 1 pretzel
gen.next('california'); // 2 california
gen.next('mayonnaise'); // 3 mayonnaise
```

And `func.bind(window, arg)` are just fancy way to call it with argument,

where `bind` method return a function...
And you can access `this` as `window` in that function...

Example:

```js
function func(args) {
    console.log(this, args)
}
func.bind("this", "args")();
```